# Javascript popup text box on submit

Tags: javascript, textbox, submit

I have a form and I know I can use onSubmit to confirm submittion but I want the user to be able to type in a text box that will be passed back to my php script on submit.

I've looked around and cant find any examples of a form being submitted and getting a popup box that you can type in text which is passed back to the script for processing.

I'm good with PHP but need a javascript master to help out here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the prompt() dialog box method and then pass the value entered by the user using GET method with your php script.
To see how to use prompt() go here:
www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp